# infinite promises in ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I am implementing REST calls in ngResource. I created the code for end point as.

```
var resource = $resource('/api/orders/:id');

// Get List of Orders

function getOrders(limit, page, designFields){
  // Query params
  var params = {
    limit: limit,
    page: page,
    designFields : designFields
  }

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  resource.query(params, function(result){
    deferred.resolve(result);
  },function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I am consuming the above in Controller as follows.

```
var orders = API.Orders.getAll(10,1);
orders
  .then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
    });
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

But the thing is I can't get any response the following spits out in Console.
There are promises inside every promise. I am confused why it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you don't get any response from the REST call? If you debug `result` does it give you what you expect?

Comment: @RyanSayles When i inspected from Network tab, the rest call went perfectly. But the promise thing is giving issues. As you can see from the console screenshot. Why it has so many objects in it :/

Comment: Can you include your getAll function code?

Comment: @MathewBerg getAll is actually getOrders()